# How can i delete key from obj2 if this key already exists in obj1? TypeScript

Tags: typescript, object

I have 2 objects and i need to merge them in one object. Then if should contain all the properties of the first object and those properties of the second that are not in the first.

here is what i tried.

`

```
function mergeObjects(obj1:object, obj2:object): object {
  const fistObj: object = { ...obj1 };
  const secondObj: object = { ...obj2 };

  for (const key in secondObj) {
    if (key in fistObj) {
      delete secondObj[key];
    }
  }

  return { ...fistObj, ...secondObj};
}
```

`

Comment: What's wrong with the current implementation? Works for me.

Comment: If you base the new object on object2 then you shouldn’t need to check if there are duplicate properties. Something like return {…object2, …object1}